# Is there a standard symbol that denotes the set of relational operators

Tags: inequality, notation, relations, order-theory

I am writing a research paper, and I would like to somehow denote the set of relational operators

$$
\left\{ =,>,<,\leq,\geq,\neq\right\} 
$$

Before I use some random symbol for that purpose, such as

$$
\Theta:=\left\{ =,>,<,\leq,\geq,\neq\right\} 
$$

so that then I can write expressions like ...$\forall\sigma\in\Theta$..., I would like to ask if a standard notation for that set exists.

I have searched Google and did not find an answer to the question; also, I don't remember seeing this in a book.

Comment: I don't remember seeing this anywhere either.  I suggest you make up a notation.  Did you mean to omit $\ne$ from the set?

Comment: It would be nice to have a place where various notational standards were listed. And conventions as well (such as some authors take a Hilbert space to be separable).

Comment: No; $\neq$ is not exactly relevant to the document I am working on, but edited the question to include it for more completeness.

Comment: @copper.hat: Indeed. Since I am using quite a lot of customized notation and conventions, I am thinking about putting all that in one place at the beginning or the end of the paper.

Comment: I look forward to a time when I can select my preferred notation/symbols and have them ripple through my library :-).